# Making a button to take a screenshot and saving it into photo gallery

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is the following code i want to take a screenshot and save into photo libary.

```js
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={styles.menuBtnCluster} 
  onPress={() => {
    RNViewShot.takeSnapshot(viewRef, {
      format: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.8
    }).then(
      uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
      error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    )}
  }
>
  <MaterialIcons name="save" size={24} color="#fff" />
  <Text style={styles.testText}>Gem</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Can you please format your question so it actually becomes readable? It will help both you and others who can give you advice

Answer (score 0):

you can use canvas element to capture the whole body element. canvas has two useful methods to do so. drawImage and toDataURL

something like:

```
let context = document.getElementById('myCanvasElement').getContext('2d');
downloadElement = document.getElementById('myAncorElement');
context.drawImage(document.body, ...);
downloadElement.href = canvasElement.toDataURL("image/png");
```